# std::cout calls in C++ is giving inconsistent results with linked list on my compiler

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've been trying to create a function that turns an array into a linked list. It creates an array of nodes the same length as the array and stores each value in the array into the data field of each node, and sets up the pointers similarly. I quickly realized it wasn't working since print() is giving undefined results after printing the data value of the first node. I used some cout calls to see what's going on and found that the two cout calls in main, even though exactly the same, produce different results on the MSVC2019 compiler. The first one produces 2 (as it should) and the second one produces an undefined result. Below is the full program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void print(Node n);
Node toNode(int ar[], int size);

int main(void) {
    int ar[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Node n = toNode(ar, 5);
    std::cout << (*(n.next)).data << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*(n.next)).data << std::endl;
    // print(n);
}

Node toNode(int ar[], int size) {
    Node nodes[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Node n;
        n.data = ar[i];
        nodes[i] = n;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        nodes[i-1].next = &nodes[i];
    }
    nodes[size-1].next = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Node n = nodes[i];
    }
    return nodes[0];
}

void print(Node n) {
    std::cout << n.data << std::endl;
    if (n.next != NULL)
        print(*n.next);
}
```

here's the output on MSVC 2019:

[image: msvc result]

I tried the same code on an online compiler and it gave a consistent 2 each time:

[image: online gdb result]

this is what I get when I call print(n) on MSVC2019:

[image: msvc print() result]

is there something wrong with the toNode() function? I tried printing out the values for each node in the nodes[] array and they were 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. I also tried printing out the value of the node that's being pointed by each node in the nodes[] array, and the results were 2, 3, 4, and 5 as expected.

also do take note there is a warning on the line

```
nodes[size-1].next = NULL;
```

in the toNode() function. The warning message is:

C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'nodes': the writable size is '552' bytes, but '-8' bytes might be written.

Comment: Undefined behavior may behave differently depending on which compiler you compile on. But you definitely have undefined behavior in your code. So your problem is *not* with "inconsistent" results, but with having bugs :) The question shouldn't presuppose the conclusion (for the results to be inconsistent you must have a reason to expect consistency first!).

Comment: You probably want to use [C++ standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), and you could take inspiration from their implementation in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or in [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). You may want to use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory)

Comment: You could also want to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (and maybe install [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop... to get good tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common problem.

The issue is that your code is using pointers to objects which have been destroyed. Take a look at your `toNode` function (with comments)

```
Node toNode(int ar[], int size) {
    Node nodes[100];
    ...
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        nodes[i-1].next = &nodes[i]; // pointers to 'nodes' being saved here
    }
    ...
    return nodes[0]; // object containing  pointers to 'nodes' returned here
}
```

The problem is that the `nodes` array is destroyed when `toNode` is exited. So all those pointers you have saved are pointing to objects that have been destroyed. This explains the inconsistent behaviour. It also explains why you can sucessfully print out all the values when you are still inside the `toNode` function, at that point the `nodes` array has not been destroyed.

When you use pointers it's up to you to make sure that the object being pointed to is not destroyed before the pointer is. C++ does not do this for you. The usual way to ensure this is to use *dynamic memory allocation* (i.e. to use `new`). This is the normal technique for creating linked lists.

Comment: ok that makes sense. It explains why after the first node (the nodes[0] being returned) the results start to become unexpected. However I'm still wondering about why the two couts are giving inconsistent results when I'm asking it to print the exact same thing.

Comment: @Remearex One answer to that question is that [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) is just that, and there's nothing more to say. But the likely real explanation for what you see is that since the `nodes` array has been destroyed the memory it occupied is now available for other uses. And that is exactly what the first `cout` is doing, it's using some of that memory, changing it in the process. And that's why the second `cout` prints something different, because the first `cout` modified the memory that used to occupied by your `nodes` array.

Comment: I see, that explains it. I freaked out when my compiler had different results for the couts while other compilers didn't.